# Running a Bing API search in Python multiple times

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, bing

I'm making a program that can search Bing for number of articles in a certain time frame (such as a day or a week) when searching by a certain country code. However, I'm trying to search for each query in a list while rerunning the program for each one and storing the results for each in another list so I can analyze the data later. Code so far is as follows:

```
countries = ["AR","AU","BR","CA",...]
numbers = []
combinedList= []
subscription_key = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
assert subscription_key
search_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search"
search_term = "G20"
headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : subscription_key}
params = {"q": search_term, "cc": countries, "freshness":"Day"}
response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
search_results = response.json()
totalRes = search_results["webPages"]['totalEstimatedMatches']
numbers.append(totalRes)
```

The "cc" section of line 9 is where you would normally try to put in the 2-digit code but I'm trying to do all of them individually.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
countries = ["AR","AU","BR","CA",...]
numbers = []
combinedList= []
subscription_key = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
assert subscription_key
search_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search"
search_term = "G20"
headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : subscription_key}

for country in countries:
    params = {"q": search_term, "cc": country, "freshness":"Day"}
    response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    search_results = response.json()
    totalRes = search_results["webPages"]['totalEstimatedMatches']
    numbers.append(totalRes)
```

You just needed to loop over the countries. Since the array `countries` contains strings, so will the variable `country` in the loop.